# make v7.widget.SwitchCompat appearance like native Switch widget

Tags: android

I tried new [v7.widget.SwitchCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) and its appearance way different from what i expect.
Did the new v7.widget.SwitchCompat supports style view  like native [Switch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) button?

Answer (score -1):

Switch is only on 4.0+

If you want to make an app that uses switch on 4.0+ devices what you need to do is declare two layouts. The first in layout-v14 which will be what's used on ICS devices. In your layout folder make use of CheckBox.

In your code make use of the CompoundButton class when getting/setting data from the switch or checkbox. You'll find that CompoundButton works well for this.

Or you can use some library like this: https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport

Comment: i'm wondering, what purpose of  v7.widget.SwitchCompat  then?